# Is Razavi wrong? ---- Two-state op for Bandgap

Tags: amplifier, integrated-circuit, ota

[image]

The picture comes from the paper "The Design of a Low-Voltage Bandgap Reference", *IEEE SOLID-STATE CIRCUITS MAGAZINE SUMMER 2021*.

I think the output of the first state should be the drain of Mb instead of the gate which shows in the picture.

Is it right, or there is something I miss.

Thanks!

Comment: It is correct. Look into current mirror opamp. The signal is passed to the output via current mirroring with \$M_{a}\$ through   \$M_{d}\$

Comment: You're sensing the common mode voltage